# Using pow with float number

Tags: objective-c

> pow ((1 + double1Value/100),  double2Value)

Is that correct ?
I need also to

```
# import "math.h"
```

i'm having some issue using that code ...

Comment: `some issue` - We are not psychics

Comment: What does that mean Camobap? This is a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your implementation is correct. I would change the other values to doubles to though.

```
pow ((1.0 + double1Value/100.0), double2Value)
```

As far as I know you do not need to import math.h

Answer (score 1):

There is `powf` specifically for floats, but you appear to be using doubles anyway which renders your current implementation correct. Should your 100 be a double too? `100.0`

There is some documentation [here](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/pow.3.asp) of both `pow` and `powf`

No need to import anything specific in objective-c.